# DatePicker placeholder is displaying wrong in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using a nullable date picker in which I used a placeholder with text as "Select Date".It is displaying well in Android, But in iOS the text is displaying as "SelecA DaAe".I am not able to understand why it is getting like that.Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which nullable DatePicker implementation are you using? Could you post code?